# How to find Region of interest of color image in matlab using opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv

I want to find Region of interest of a color image in MatLab.
Is it good to use openCV inside matlab to find ROI?

Please help me how to achieve this

Comment: Depends. You can probably do it in just Matlab, or just OpenCV. Altogether your question is very vague and not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab and OpenCV are two completely different things. OpenCV is a vision library that you can use in C++ or Python, and you should see Matlab as a programming language, which uses its own libraries (toolboxes), among those you may be interested in the [Image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) and the [Computer vision system toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/).

Comment: hehe, if you look at the wiki, you'll see devs there working on a mex for opencv ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to *manually* mark a ROI in Matlab there are few ways to do it. The easiest, is to use

```
BW = roipoly.
```

See [roipoly documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html)

To the best of my knowledge, no similar generic function such as Matlab's roipoly exists in OpenCV.